# Javascript - modal select option (unable to select item in modal)

Tags: javascript, html

Could someone kindly advise me how I go about expanding my code?

What I want to do is:

- When the `plots_container` is clicked, this prompts up a modal with a list of charts in it
- When the user clicks on a chart (eg: `line plot` in the modal), the content in the span stating `hello` hello changes to `<span>line plot</span>`
- I would like to do something exactly like [this](https://codepen.io/bianchimro/pen/epYYQO?editors=101)

At the moment I have just managed to prompt up the modal when `plots_container` is clicked.

I would be very grateful if someone could take a look at what I've tried in the below files and provide suggestions or feedback.

index.html

```
<span class="modal_content">
    <select class="hide seriesDetails" title="Type of Chart for this Series" id="ChartType" name="ChartType"><option selected="selected" value="17">Pie</option></select>
    <div class="seriesDetails" id="plots_container">
        <span>hello</span>
    </div>
    <div id="plotList">
        <ul>
            <li class="business">
                <div class="image_text_content">
                    <div class="image_container"><img src="Content/images/plot-thumbs/1-scatter-plot.jpg" alt="scatter-plot"></div>
                    <div class="plot_title">scatter plot</div>
                </div>
                <div class="image_text_content">
                    <div class="image_container"><img src="Content/images/plot-thumbs/2-line-plot.jpg" alt="scatter-plot"></div>
                    <div class="plot_title">line plot</div>
                </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
     </div>
 </span>
```

application.js

```
// modal to display types of plots
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#plots_container').click(function() {
    $('#plotList').fadeToggle();
  })
  $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $("#plotList");
    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
      && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
      container.fadeOut();
    }
  }); 
});
```

[image]

Comment: Note that you're missing a closing `div` inside the `span.modal_content`.

Answer (score 0):

A quick JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hxnm7q2L/1/ to show how you can use an

```
.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
```

to trigger showing the value changing of a selected value in a modal.

Comment: @ARTLoe, did either of these answers provide you with what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood what you want, you could try something like this:

```
$('.plot_title').click(function(event){
  $('#plots_container > span').html(event.target.innerText);
})
```

Though it would work only with html-structure that you've provided, since it has very specific css-selectors.

Comment: thanks vadim, unfortunately the `<span></span>` is not filled with the text `line plot` when `$('.image_text_content:nth-child(2)')` is clicked. I tried to see if i could make this work, but no success. Your advise would be much helpful

Comment: i tried something like this: `console.log($('#plots_container > span').innerHTML = $('.plot_title'));`

Comment: @ARTLoe If this is JQuery, `$('#plots_container > span')` will return you a Jquery object, not a DOM-element, therefore it doesn't have innerHTML. It has html() method instead, without param to get value, and with param to set.
Try there `console.log($('.plot_title').html())`, to make sure that you are getting correct value, and the function being called at all.